# get an array element where another element is known?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [what] => b4
            [map] => 74,76,77,83
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [what] => b2
            [map] => 53,82
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [what] => b1
            [map] => 36
        )
 )

abc('b4');

function abc($what){
    $map = // element `map` where `what` = $what;
}
```

So I need to get `map` where `what` is equal to `$what`;

For example - if `$what` is `b4` result should be `74,76,77,83`; and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes in `function abc('$what')`

Comment: @NigelRen, thanks, correct.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller long story short - I'm getting this array from database, and trying to avoid to quering the database very often.

Comment: Why not use a loop and pass the array as a parameter?

Comment: @Thefourthbird loop database result or array elements? Could you give an example, pls?

Comment: Loop the array like https://3v4l.org/MZF3Y

Comment: `echo $array[array_search("b4", array_column($array, 'what'))]['map'];` -> https://3v4l.org/0NpcX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) you can get the matching `$map` in one line:

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    Array
        (
            "what" => "b4",
            "map" => "74,76,77,83"
        ),
   Array
        (
            "what" => "b2",
            "map" => "53,82"
        ),
    Array
        (
            "what" => "b1",
            "map" => "36"
        )
 );

function abc($array, $what) {
   return $array[array_search($what, array_column($array, 'what'))]['map'];
}   

echo abc($array, "b4");
```

The function de-constructed and explained:

```
function abc($array /* the complete input array */, $what /* the search string */) {
   // get the key of the sub-array that has $what in column 'what':
   $key = array_search($what, array_column($array, 'what'));
   // use that key to get 'map' on index $key
   return $array[$key]['map'];
}
```

A working fiddle can be found here: https://3v4l.org/0NpcX

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to access the data on a regular basis and the `what` is unique, then use `array_column()` with the third parameter as the column to use as the key.  Then your array is easily access with `what` and no loops are harmed in this answer...

```
$array = Array
(
    Array
    (
        "what" => "b4",
        "map" => "74,76,77,83"
        ),
    Array
    (
        "what" => "b2",
        "map" => "53,82"
        ),
    Array
    (
        "what" => "b1",
        "map" => "36"
        )
    );

$array = array_column($array, null, "what");

echo $array['b4']['map'];
```

gives...

```
74,76,77,83
```

Comment: upvote for _"and no loops are harmed in this answer"_ - A clever solution, anyway!

Comment: Null means return the same array associative on "what". Just run the code and var_dump $array and you will see.

Comment: Using null in the second parameter means to keep the whole element as it is. Try print_r($array) to see the results

Comment: @Jeff I'm quite sure there is a loop under the hood.

Comment: Php is a loop, how do you think it executes any code

Answer (score 2):

I think "walking" through an array is easy to read and understand:

```
<?php
$map = [
    [
        'what' => "b4",
        'map' => "74,76,77,83"
    ],
    [
            'what' => "b2",
            'map' => "53,82"
    ],
    [
            'what' => "b1",
            'map' => "36"
    ]
];

function lookupWhatInMap(&$map, $what) {
    array_walk($map, function($entry, $key) use ($what) {
        if ($entry['what'] == $what) {
            print_r($entry['map']);
        }
    });
}

lookupWhatInMap($map, "b4");
```

Comment: This is the only answer as I see it that can find more than one item. All other return or overwrite if I understand them correct.

Comment: @Andreas Might be, but that is not an explicit requirement mentioned in the question.. And all other answers can easily be modified to collect matches in a result array...

Comment: I know. Just wanted to mention it to anyone looking at the answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is loop through your map and compare values.

```
function abc($what){
    $map = [...];
    foreach($map as $item) {
        if (isset($item[$what]) ) {
            return $item["map"];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want 1 value from the array, you could use a foreach and a return statement where there is a match:

```
$a = [
    [
        "what" => "b4",
        "map" => "74,76,77,83"
    ],
    [
        "what" => "b2",
        "map" => "53,82"
    ],
    [
        "what" => "b1",
        "map" => "36"
    ]
];
function abc($what, $arrays)
{
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        if ($array['what'] === $what) {
            return $array['map'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

echo(abc('b4', $a)); // 74,76,77,83
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FBFQ9)

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/V9WNNx

```
$arr[] = [
            'what' => 'b4',
            'map' => '74,76,77,83'
        ];
$arr[] = [
            'what' => 'b2',
            'map' => '53,82'
        ];
$arr[] = [
            'what' => 'b1',
            'map' => '36'
        ];

echo abc('b4', $arr);

function abc($what, $arr){
    $map = null;
    $idx = array_search($what, array_column($arr, 'what'));
    if ($idx !== false) {
        $map = $arr[$idx]['map'];
    }
    return $map;
}
```